# Cannot get module reference

Tags: node.js, npm

I encountered a strange error while trying to use underscore module in a certain file, although I can use it in other files within the same project. I think the problem is not related underscore module itself.

The beginning of file is the following:

```
...
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('underscore');
...
```

Then, when I try to use underscore within a function, I get an error

```
'‌ReferenceError: _ is not defined'
```

If I try to use other modules within the same function, everything works well and also, if I use underscore in other files, it also works fine so I don't know what is wrong.

I tried to delete node_modules folder and run npm update but the issue is still present.

Below is the folder structure, which includes only relevant files and folders:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bower.json
├── default.json
├── lib
│   ├── dbHelper.js
├── node_modules
├── routes
│   ├── api.js
```

In api.js underscore works fine, whereas in dbHelper.js doesn't work.

Has anyone encountered similar problem? Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to solve it?

‌

Comment: @robertklep, no, I checked everything and also tried to change variable name from _ to underscore but the problem is still present.

Comment: try declaring it simply like _ = require('underscore') to make it a global variable. Remove the var keyword

Comment: @Kamesh if it is declared as a global variable, it works.

Comment: What is the architecture of your project? Importing it as `var _ = require('underscore');` is correct and will allow you to use it within the scope it was imported (so everywhere within the same file, assuming you have imported it in the top scope. The fact that you need to omit the `var` keyword is a hint that something else is wrong. Just blindly importing it globally is a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @msanford, I completely agree with you and would prefer to find a cause instead of doing 'dirty' workaround. I added the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Given the addition of your architecture: you need to `require()` the module in every scope (in your case, file) in which you use it. In this case, add var _ = require('underscore'); to your `dbHelper.js` file.

Have no fear: Node.js maintains a *[require cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)* that maintains a list of loaded modules in memory to prevent it having to reload from disk every time it encounters a `require()` statement for the same module: it will re-use the one in memory from the first time it was loaded.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have added var _ = require('underscore') in dbHelper.js but it doesn't work.

Comment: @NikoGamulin Can you post the whole `dbHelper.js` file (if it's very long, make [a gist](https://gist.github.com/) and we can extract the relevant parts, if there are any, into the question)? Perhaps there's a structure to the file that prevents `_`  from being seen by the scope in which you call it.